Docker Wordpress two sites in one domain with Nginx proxy manager
I have nginx proxy manager and I want to install wordpress. No problem but if I want to install inside the wordpress a link inside the same web I can not find the way. I mean I have https://whatever.com and I want to install another web in https://whatever.com/anotherwordpress I do not found the way. The file wpconfig is where you use to configure the database and everything but in the files from wordpress with docker that file does not have the configuration file. I use this docker-compose.yaml
services:
  db:
    # We use a mariadb image which supports both amd64 & arm64 architecture
    image: mariadb:10.6.4-focal
    # If you really want to use MySQL, uncomment the following line
    #image: mysql:8.0.27
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=somewordpress
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
      - MYSQL_USER=wordpress
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=wordpress
    expose:
      - 3306
      - 33060
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - wp_data:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: always
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
volumes:
  db_data:
  wp_data:

Any way to do it?
Thanks in advance

Do you mean wordpress multisite or are these two separate wordpress instances?

I know how to do two separate instances changing the ports and everything. I mean, in the same wp container http://blabla.com and creating a subfolder in the volume of docker and install another http://blabla.com/another_blabla. Thanks
